# Tablet Camera api says Zoom unsupported but

Tags: camera, win-universal-app, uwp

The basic camera functions are working ok, but the property: mediaCapture.VideoDeviceController.ZoomControl.Supported is always false.  Also, the built-in camera app's preview will not zoom.  I thought maybe the camera was just incapable, but I installed a free trial of a camera app that zooms during preview just fine (https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/store/apps/cas/9wzdncrddbt1).

I am waiting until I see the preview screen and then examining the property on my mediaCapture object.  The *.Capabilities.Supported is also false.

I have 2 tablets (identical hardware) and it happens on both.  They are loaners and I am not sure of the brand (they are in rugged cases without any logos).

Could this be a driver issue?  Or an OS version issue?  One tablet has Windows 10 Enterprise and the other Windows Pro.  I can't figure out why the store app is able to zoom if there's a real issue.

Comment: ^I emailed a Microsoft support person who responded that the Zoom property would only be enabled if the camera supports "optical zoom" and that the app I mentioned must be doing "digital zoom" (just cropping and then enlarging the cropped section to the original size).   Sound correct???   I don't see why they have the flag if it would never be enabled!?!